# How to automatic run ida plugin after IDA Parse PE file

Tags: ida-plugin

I wrote an idaplugin with idapython, but it has some function that only works after IDA is done parsing the input file and displays the disassembly window. So, is there a way to automatically run a plugin after IDA has finished parsing?

P/S: I tried using IDBHooks but everytime I hook in IDA crashes, therefore I want to find another way without hooks.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like `idaapi.autoWait()` is what you are looking for. Simply add it to the beginning of your script.

Comment: `idaapi.autoWait()` pause all my script, so IDA will be crashed

Comment: If you are waiting for IDA to finish analysis before executing your script or calling your function then call `idaapi.autoWait()`. It will wait/pause until IDA is completed with its analysis. Once the analysis is completed it will return control/execution back to the script. You might need to call it at the beginning of your function rather than beginning of the script.